# how can we auto generate ID on a button click that will contain the concatenation of date,month,year plus a counter?

Tags: java, date

```
public class CalendarUtil

{

    private Calendar cal = null;

    public String getRemId()

    {

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        return "" + cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +        cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    }        
}
```

How can we auto generate ID on a button click that will contain the concatenation of date,month,year and a 3 digit counter starting form 000 and display it in a textfield? for eg:- 28122012001, 28122012002, etc and so on. Code that i have been trying is as above

Comment: Please, reformat your question using the built-in editor! :) Thanks!

Comment: how can we auto generate ID on a button click that will contain the concardination of date,month,year and a 3 digit counter starting form 000 and display it in a textfield for eg:- 28122012001, 28122012002, etc and so on. Code that i have been trying is as above

Comment: That should go in the question, please click the edit button and add the text. Read on How to Ask here http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Are you using a database? It sounds like you have the date part solved.

Comment: yes brother i am using a database but for the database i need a primary key, which i want to generate on the java GUI and then insert it to database...... can u help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think two static fieds can do it.

```
private static String lastUsedDatePrefix;
private static int counter;
```

If you want to nenerate a new ID, check if the dateprefix is the same as stored in `lastUsedDatePrefix` if yes, increment `counter` else set `counter=0` and set `lastUsedDatePrefix`to actual date.

Untested implementation:

```
public class CalendarUtil{
    private static String lastUsedDatePrefix = "";
    private static int counter = 0;

    public String getRemId(){
        final String datePrefix = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyy").format(new Date());
        if (lastUsedDatePrefix.equals(datePrefix)) {
            CalendarUtil.counter++;
        }
        else{
            CalendarUtil.lastUsedDatePrefix = datePrefix;
            CalendarUtil.counter = 0;
        }
        final String counterSuffix = ((100 <= CalendarUtil.counter) ? ""
                : (10 <= CalendarUtil.counter) ? "0" : "00")
                + CalendarUtil.counter;
        return datePrefix + counterSuffix;
     }   
}
```

Comment: can i request u to plz elaborate this a little bit more as i am new to java sir..??

Comment: I would change the date-format to yyyyMMdd this way the order as a String would match the order of the generated IDs. [give it  a thought]

Comment: You will get still unique but not nice IDs if you generate more than 1000 IDs at one day. => maybe you should increase the counter-suffix by some digits.

Comment: sir according to my need i think it wont go beyond 300 to 400 ID's in one day...:-)

Comment: how can i get the values in a text field plzzz help...??

Comment: call `setText(String id)` on the TextField